# Replace values inside a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where the column is a list. I'm trying to replace a value inside that list using the [replace method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), but with no success.  I'm trying to replace the string *other* by *Any value*

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales_niche' : [['B2B', 'Services', 'Services', 'Other', 'Other']]})


df['sales_niche'].replace('Other','Any value')
df['sales_niche'].replace({ 'Other': 'Any value' })
```

output

```
0        [B2B, Services, Services, Other, Other]
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? When working with columns that aren't lists it works fine. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be easy to make a small example dataframe and show us in code what you are doing.

Comment: Just did it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` only works with the **exact** values, or substring if `regex=True`. In your case, you have list of strings, so `replace` wouldn't be a good choice.

Generally, lists inside dataframe should be avoided. If you must use it, you can just loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales_niche':[['B2B', 'Services', 'Services', 'Other', 'Other']]})

d = { 'Other': 'Any value' }

df['sales_niche'].apply(lambda x: [d[a] if a in d else a for a in x])
```

Output:

```
0    [B2B, Services, Services, Any value, Any value]
Name: sales_niche, dtype: object
```

You can also explode your data and use `replace`, then aggregate back:

```
df['sales_niche'].explode().replace(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

but the overhead might make this approach not as useful as the simple apply above.

Answer (score 1):

Using this dataframe as example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales_niche' : [['B2B', 'Services', 'Services', 'Other', 'Other']]})
```

running this code

```
repl = { 'Other': 'Any value' }
df['sales_niche'] = df['sales_niche'].apply(lambda l:[repl.get(e,e) for e in l])
df
```

gives you this

```
sales_niche
0   [B2B, Services, Services, Any value, Any value]
```